# tapping on portion of view changes view to previous view controller unexpectedly

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue

I have a project with 4 view controllers. 2 of these view controllers have a toolbar with a back button. Tapping anywhere on the right lower 2/3 of the screen on the controllers with a back button triggers a segue to the previous view controller - but none of the code in `prepareForSegue` is executed, and I haven't written any segues except for in the toolbar buttons, so the view shouldn't be transitioning to the previous view anyway.

How can I even debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is expected with page curl transition style, oops!

Changing the transition style "solved" it